# Hyper V enabled but virtualization not enabled

Tags: windows, hyper-v, docker, bios

I installed Docker on the latest Windows OS and got the following message
"Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS."
Hyper V is definitely enabled. 
However, the Performance tab of the Task Manager tells me that virtualisation is disabled. How do I enable it?

Comment: Hi o-t-w make sure you check your bios settings as suggested by @magikmw if virtualization is still not starting try BCDedit /SET hypervisorlsunchtype AUTO then reboot. info baouth BCDEDIT cand be found in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My issue here was that Hyper-V needed to be enabled on Windows 10 before the OS actually enabled virtualization: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Answer (score 2):

Look into your BIOS settings.
Depending on the hardware, you need a different key or combination of keys to get into BIOS settings at system boot. While there look for virtualization support, and specifically Intel VT-d (I assume here you have an Intel CPU).
Saving and restarting into the OS should enable virtualization.

Edit:
[This article from RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html) provides perhaps a better explanation of above, see point 4.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, when I was installing *Docker Desktop* on my Windows Machine, there is a simple solution to this issue:

1. Go to system setup(BIOS Setup) when your computer starts booting
2. Go to **Device Configuration**
3. Find **Virtualization** and then click the checkbox to enable it
4. Restart your Machine

If you are having Hp PC/Laptop then follow the following steps:

1. Press **ESC** while Booting
2. It will redirect you to main Setup menu
3. Press **F10** to go to BIOS Setup
4. Find out **Device Configuration** option
5. Search for **Virtualization** in it
6. Check It and restart your Machine

For More Details: [HP Customer Support - Knowledge Base](https://support.hp.com/hk-en/document/c03824350)